# How to replicate command string to URL on cgywin/curl?

Tags: bash, api, curl, weather-api

Currently I am using the following url string to obtain weather data from openweathermap.org.

Example: http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=New%20York&appid={apikey}

In response I receive

```
{"coord":{"lon":-74.01,"lat":40.71},"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04d"}],"base":"cmc stations","main":{"temp":264.268,"pressure":1033,"humidity":53,"temp_min":264.268,"temp_max":264.268,"sea_level":1048.16,"grnd_level":1033},"wind":{"speed":1.62,"deg":73.5001},"clouds":{"all":68},"dt":1455544776,"sys":{"message":0.0048,"country":"US","sunrise":1455536990,"sunset":1455575462},"id":5128581,"name":"New York","cod":200}
```

I would like to replicate the above on cygwin/curl.

Below is one of my many failed attempts.

```
$ curl -X POST --data "q=London&appid={apikey}" http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather
{"cod":401, "message": "Invalid API key. Please see http://openweathermap.org/faq#error401 for more info."}
```

But the API key works if I use directly on the URL

**Question:** How can I access this API using curl?

**References:**

- [Weather API](http://www.openweathermap.org/api)
- [JSON Editor Online](http://jsoneditoronline.org/)
- [How to clear ambiguity in Open Weather Map API JSON response for weather forecast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31832424/how-to-clear-ambiguity-in-open-weather-map-api-json-response-for-weather-forecas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just bash, yes? I don't have an API key, but this should work if I did.

```
OPENWEATHER_API_KEY="something"
curl "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=New%20York&appid=$OPENWEAHTER_API_KEY"
```

Output

```
{"cod":401, "message": "Invalid API key. Please see http://openweathermap.org/faq#error401 for more info."}
```